# UnitOfWork exception triggered by flush between deletes

Tags: eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink with container managed entity managers. I have been attempting to determine the cause of a QueryException I sometimes see during delete. The exception description is:

> The object MySubEntity is not from this UnitOfWork object space, but the parent session's.

Here's a simplified depiction of the model:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity
{
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = MySubEntity.class,
               cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },
               orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private List<MySubEntity> subEntities;
}
```

What I have discovered is that the following succeeds:

```
MyEntity firstEntity = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, firstKey);
MyEntity secondEntity = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, secondKey);

entityManager.remove(firstEntity);
//entityManager.flush();
entityManager.remove(secondEntity);
```

but if I uncomment the flush, this fails with the QueryException.

The code shown was only written to verify the problem, in practice the deletes don't occur so close together and the flush is implicitly triggered by a read query.

I verified this behavior with both EclipseLink 2.5.1 and 2.6.2. Is this a known EclipseLink bug? I couldn't find one documented. Is this expected behavior?

I have tried calling UnitOfWork.validateObjectSpace() both before and after the first delete but validateObjectSpace() succeeds in both cases.

Comment: I have entity with exactly your mapping and tried your sequence with `remove` and it worked both with and without `flush`. Too little information is here. How is your other entity mapped? BTW: Sometimes the easiest way to solve these things is to debug it all the way down to EclipseLink library. Isn't there some `MySubEntity` sharing between `MyEntity` objects? Does it still do it when `orphanRemoval = false`?

Comment: In addition to validateObjectSpace, try using printIdentityMaps() and also traverse your secondEntity to see if something in the object graph isn't being placed in the UnitOfWork cache - this might occur if a managed instance is set to reference a read-only instance.  Is the EntityManager clear before the find operations, or is it appart of a long running operation?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue in my own work and while looking for help I stumbled upon this question. I can't say for certain if my issue is the same but it is quite similar. My goal is to possibly help others who find this as well.

Let me first explain the slight differences in my model compared to the question. I do not think these differences should be much of a problem however I am including them in the event I am wrong (or it helps someone in the future). The relationship between MyEntity and MySubEntity is not a list and is one to one. It is named accordingly.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity
{
    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUB_ENTITY_KEY")
    private MySubEntity subEntity;
}
```

Execution:

- My execution is essentially the same as the question. Use the entity manager to remove multiple  entities and flush. The flush is not required for my issue to occur (since the entity manager will eventually flush automatically) however it does make it fail faster.

Expected Results:

- I expect the removal of both `firstEntity` and `secondEntity` and their respective subEntity objects     should be removed as well since they are now orphans.

Actual Results:

- The UnitOfWork exception described in the question. What I found is that EclipseLink is unable to properly handle the relationship upon remove when multiple MyEntity objects are being removed. This doesn't seem to happen in every situation but if you are able to produce a situation to confuse EclipseLink it will produce this exception consistently.

Solution:

- Manually disassociate MyEntity and subEntity prior to removal. This can be done trivially by doing `myEntity1.setSubEntity(null);`
- Even better would be adding it into the pre removal of MyEntity so it is automatically disassociated.

Example:

```
@PreRemove
public void onRemove() {
    this.subEntity= null;
}
```

Platform Info:

- EclipseLink v2.4.3
- Oracle JRE 1.7.0_79
- Weblogic 12.1.2